# Why can't I add a subView to my stackView without making the stackView a lazy var?

Tags: swift

Pretty much the title; trying to add 2 labels to the stackView while making it (the stack view) a constant results in the error

```
Instance member 'labelOne' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'
```

However, making stackView a lazy var makes the issue go away.

Why is that? And is this the only way to resolve this issue; ie, is it possible to let them be constants and not have this issue crop up?

Edit:

Code:

```
let labelOne: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28, weight: .bold)
    label.text = "Label One"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    return label
}()


let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [labelOne]) //ERROR
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.axis = .horizontal
        return sv
    }()
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference has to do with the timing of when those variables' values are set up. Both `labelOne` and `stackView` are instance members on your ViewController, and both will get a value that's returned from a closure (from the surrounding `{ … }()` syntax).

However, a "regular" property declared this way will run the closure as soon as your ViewController is initialized, while a lazy property will wait to run the closure until the property is first accessed — well *after* initialization. The practical difference between these is that `self` is available to closures run lazily, but `self` is *not* available to closures run at initialization time. (The `self` that you'd use is still being initialized!)

The other gotcha here is that it might not even look like you're accessing `self` in either closure! However, in Swift, whenever you access a member property, it implicitly uses `self` — so your reference to `labelOne` inside the second closure is really to `self.labelOne`, which is where the requirement that `self` be fully initialized comes from. Making that closure `lazy` lets `self` get ready before it's evaluated, which allows your code to compile.

The usual alternate approach here is to explicitly initialize all your view controller's subviews inside `viewDidLoad()`, and declare the properties themselves as implicitly unwrapped optionals (IUOs). This would look something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var labelOne: UILabel!
    var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelOne = …
        stackView = …
    }
}
```

This has been called "two-stage initialization," and is implicitly recommended by [Apple's View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningYourSubclass.html):

> Calls the view controller’s `viewDidLoad` method.
>   Use this method to add or remove views, modify layout constraints, and load data for your views.